# Omnifaces 2.5.1 and multiple WARs inside EAR

Tags: cdi, war, ear, omnifaces

I have an application that works fine runing Omnifaces 2.5.1 Mojarra under Wildfly 10. This application have a multiple WARs but only one uses Omnifaces.

Today I tried to add Omnifaces to use in a second WAR inside the EAR. And I'm getting this exception:

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Long with qualifiers @Param
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Param private siscom.web.jsf.controller.PartnerDetailsController.id
  at siscom.web.jsf.controller.PartnerDetailsController.id(PartnerDetailsController.java:0)
WELD-001475: The following beans match by type, but none have matching qualifiers:
  - Producer Method [Long] with qualifiers [@BatchProperty @Any] declared as [[UnbackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @BatchProperty public org.jberet.creation.BatchBeanProducer.getLong(InjectionPoint)]

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

My controller is:

```
@ViewScoped @Named
public class PartnerDetailsController implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    @Param
    private Long id;
}
```

Note: Sometimes work fine, sometimes doesn't. When I restart the application works. If I restart again, not works.

Comment: how did you get your hands on Omnifaces 2.6? Current release is 2.5.1

Comment: Sorry. Its a typo. I'll fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `@Param` with multiple `WAR`s containing Omnifaces packaged in an `EAR`. This is an interaction bug between CDI and OF.

Related blog post: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/cdi-behaved-unexpectedly-in-ear-so.html

I have not tested it lately if it works in the latest version.